# Matrix multiplication and determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I seem to notice the following: Suppose we have two matrices, $M$ and $N$. Suppose that $|M|$ and $|N|$ are both $1$. Then if $MN = Q$, then $|Q| = 1$. If $NM = R$, then $|R| = 1$. If $|M|$ and $|N|$ are both $-1$, then if $MN = A$, then $|A| = 1$. If $NM = B$, then $|B| = 1$. If $|M| = -1$ and $|N| = 1$, then if $MN = C$, then $|C| = -1$. And if $|M| = 1$ and $|N| = -1$, then if $MN = D$, then $|D| = -1$. Are there proofs for all of these statements? Thanks. (Sometimes some of these results are different but they do roughly hold. So sometimes the determinant of the product is $1$, even if one of the factors has a determinant of $-1$, and the other has a determinant of $1$.)

Answer (score 5):

Indeed:

If $A$, $B$ are square $n\times n$ matrices, then $\det(AB) = \det (A)\det (B)$.

Thus, the determinant is a [multiplicative map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Multiplicativity_and_matrix_groups), which follows from the [linearity of the determinant function](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product).

What you discovered are examples of this phenomenon. You might extend your exploration to confirm this with more examples: $$|A| = 2,\;|B| = n \implies \det(AB) = 2n = \det A\cdot \det B $$ and $$|A| = 0,\;|B| = n \implies \det(AB) = 0 = 0\cdot n = \det A\cdot \det B$$

Indeed, we can build much upon this: E.g., $$\det(AB) = 0 \implies (\det A = 0 \;\;\text{OR}\;\;\det B = 0).$$

Comment: Ah ok. I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU! +1

Answer (score 2):

The general statement is that the determinant satisfies the following:
$$
\det(MN)=\det(M)\det(N)
$$
This covers all of your cases.  Yes, there [are proofs for this.](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product)  So to your parenthetical statement: there are no matrices $M,N$ such that $\det(M)=1$, $\det(N)=-1$, and $\det(MN)=1$.